# tensorflow 2 capsule network implementation reshape is not working

Tags: python, keras, type-conversion, reshape, tensorflow2.0

I am working on capsule network implementation in TensorFlow version-2-gpu. while I am doing reshaping on the output of the convolution layer(tensor) it gives the error of attempt to convert the value. error and my code are as below.

```
 conv1_params = {"filters": 256,"kernel_size": 9,"strides": 1,"padding": 
                  "valid","activation":tf.nn.relu,}
 conv2_params = {"filters": caps1_n_maps * caps1_n_dims,"kernel_size":9,"strides": 2,"padding": 
                 "valid","activation": tf.nn.relu}
 conv1 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(input_shape=(None,28,28,1), name="conv1", **conv1_params)
 conv2 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(name="conv2", **conv2_params)
 #output shape of conv1=TensorShape([None, 20, 20, 256])
 #output shape of conv2=TensorShape([None, 6, 6, 256])
 caps1_raw=tf.keras.backend.reshape(conv2,shape=[-1,caps1_n_caps,caps1_n_dims])
```

## error

> ValueError: Attempt to convert a value
>   () with an unsupported type () to a Tensor.

Comment: your output `conv2` is of 4 dimensions, and you trying to reshape it to 3 dimensions of shape `(256,caps1_n_caps, caps1_n_dims)`,the first one is batch size in `conv2`

Comment: @ShubhamShaswat , But when I am doing it with TensorFlow version 1.x like this caps1_raw = tf.reshape(conv2, [-1, caps1_n_caps, caps1_n_dims],
                       name="caps1_raw")  , it works and return with this dimension which is expected  <tf.Tensor 'caps1_raw:0' shape=(?, 1152, 8) dtype=float32> ,     problem is with version 2.